# What really does the 'View Setup and Configuration' permission do?

Tags: permissions, permission-sets

I have a managed package and when this permission isnt checked, I get a 'resource does not exist'
I am asking because this needs to be a permission for customers to be able to use my package. I am checking field level access in the code, to make sure they have access to the right fields. It seems 'View Setup and Configuration' is required for that. I check for vf page access/ field permissions/ api enabled on profile, and object and field level access. is 'View Setup and Configuration' required for that? Need an explanation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Users with this permission can View the organization setup details on the Setup pages, Run user reports, View the setup audit trail, Check field accessibility for users. Doubt in your package there could be such instances accessing any of them.
If you own the package's Dev org, You could debug it in your Dev org as a less privileged user to find where it exactly fails.

Comment: What permissions are you checking and how? Please be more specific.

Comment: @PasanEeriyagama run user reports, like on behalf of, or in general run reports?

Answer (score 3):

[User profile permission descriptions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000198725&type=1)

> View Setup and Configuration - Allows the user to view the App Setup
>   menu and Administrative Settings pages.